# how to select data on sql using group by

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

i have table
[image]

i would like to select like this
[image]

how to get data count_attendance?

Comment: What have you tried? What errors have you gotten? Have you even tried? You should update your question with any queries or error messages you've gotten.

Comment: I don't know what you want to get.. the `count_attendance` is count based on how many line of `AAA` counted??

Comment: i already try "select id, name, gol, count(attendance) from example group by name". i confuse to select count_attendance, if attendance 'yes' then count else attendance 'no' not count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use subquery to do that:

`select name, gol, count(attendance) as count_data,(Select count(attendance) from tablename n where n.attendance='yes' and n.name=tablename.name and n.gol=tablename.gol) as count_attendance from tablename group by name,gol`

Just replace tablename with the name of your table.